# NASM string from user input not comparing

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, intel

It's my second day I'm learning NASM and assembly language at all, so I've decided to write a kind of a calculator. The problem is that when user enters the operation, the program doesn't compare it.I mean compares but it doesn't consider that strings are equal when they are. I've googled a lot, but no results. What might be my broblem? Here's source

```
operV   resb    255  ; this is declaration of variable later used to store the input, in .bss of course

mov rax, 0x2000003         ;here user enters the operation, input is "+", or "-"
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, operV
mov rdx, 255
syscall

mov rax, operV             ; here is part where stuff is compared
mov rdi, "+"         
cmp rax, rdi
je add

mov rdi, "-"
cmp rax, rdi
je substr
;etc...
```

Comment: You're loading the address, did you mean `mov rax, [rel operV]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You also press the enter key when you submit information like that. change rdi to "+", 10 on linux, or "+", 11 on windows

The answer came to me in a dream last night.

```
operV resd 4; Resd because registers are a dword in size, and we want the comparison to be as seamless ass possible, you can leave this as 255, but thats a little excessive as we only need 4

mov rax, 0x2000003
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi. operV
mov rdx, 4 ;You only need 4 bytes (1 dword) as this is all we are accepting (+ and line end, then empty space so it matches up with the register we are comparing too) you can leave this as 255 too, but again, we only need 4
syscall

mov rax, operV
mov rdi, "x", 10
cmp dword[rax], rdi ; You were comparing the pointer in rax with rdi, not the content pointed to by rax with rdi. now we are comparing the double word (4 bytes) at the location pointed too by rax (operV) and comparing them. Instead of comparing the location of operV with the thing you want.
je add
```

That's the changes done :P

Comment: It didn't help, but I had to add new constant to define            'plus db "+", 10 ' and then 'mov rdi, plus' but still, the result is negative.P.S. Watched your NASM tutorials on youtube, why have you dropped it? Tey were the best tutorials i found on youtube.

Comment: Best compliment to date, they haven't stopped, I dont have a stable linux distro to work on at the moment, slackware is screwed up for me. When I have a stable distro we're gonna do them again, feel free to subscribe, I want to get more dont before next month if I'm around

Comment: Can you please give a working example, because I still don't figure out how to make it work, an example of comparing user input with a string.

Comment: Hmmm my experience with this is mostly in 32 bit nasm. Not too familiar with 64 bit, is this linux kernel, and are you using sys_read from stdin?

Comment: I am writing under mac os x, but the only difference on this level is that you add 0x200000 before 3(sys_read), then start instead of _start and rax, rdi,rsi,rdx instead of eax,ebx,ecx,edx. So if you'll write 32 bit linux code i'll understand. Thanks!

Comment: It should now answer your question, I've adapted it to OS X code for you too

Comment: Thanks, in OS X new line's also 10